# Extrude and separate faces

Tags: python

I have a bulding floorplan with a few hundred rooms where each room is a separate face. I now want to convert these into separate volume objects and I tinking of somting like this:

1. Select the faces in edit mode (there are lots of other faces like walls and doors).
2. Make a copy of each face.
3. Extrude the faces in Z with a given height, for example 3 m.
4. Separate the new geometry into a new object

It works fine for one or two but I need to automize this process with a script and wonder if someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following commands and it worked rather fine but it is very slow.

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split()
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```